# Examples of block-layout UI design?

Tags: website-design, page-layout, css, website-templates, interface-design

By block-layout, I mean style like these:
[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

[Medium](https://medium.com/collections),[Readwrite](http://readwrite.com/),[Kicktarter](http://www.kickstarter.com)

There aren't too many on gallery sites(for example, [Flat UI Design](http://fltdsgn.com/)). Most of them are for product promotion, making a big focus at first. Like this:
[image]

And I'm design a website needing block-layout, and really need more examples for inspiration. Where could I find them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you are aiming at; to me it seems your examples simply are website based on a grid (which basically all sites are...), but where the modular grid is clearly defined by images of coloured boxes. Any search for

- grid webdesign
- website design
- swiss design

  would give you an exhaustive plethora of examples.

If you aim at basically mainly *images* in a grid, a loose suggestion could be [Masonry JS library](http://masonry.desandro.com/). Your question is not very specific, so a clarification as to what material you have to work with, what the aim is, where you get stuck would maybe give you a better answer.

**Edit:**
Any framework for web will have an alternative of this extremely simple layout. As I do not know what needs you have, wordpress, bootstrap, joomla, boilerplate all have this simple div structure. If you are looking to *create* this layout from the bottom, any search for "simple css three column" would give you example files. Or, indeed, a search for "example three column web layout".

Comment: See my UPDATE. I mean just rectangle-style layout.

Comment: ...but do you mean inspiration, or practical web frameworks?

Comment: Just examples for inspirations. But is there any framework for this? I've used `Mansory` before, but it is for cascading effect. For `rectangle`, I feel it just needs border, margin etc..

Comment: Ahh....Its not just `sidebar` style. I mean the `rectangle`, it has height and gaps between them. In the `medium` example, it is the collection reprensented by a photo and its title. In `ReadWrite`, every story is also presented in a rectangular shape. I want to see more this kind of style: how the information(title, image, content) get presented and what color(for border, background etc.) combination they use. Am I Clear?

Comment: Or It is more like win8's metro style?

Comment: Hm, but I do not understand the problem. You need _inspiration_ and my examples would certainly give you that. As for the practical execution, this is incredibly simple in css. _All_ websites have the basic "boxed" framework with repeated divs. If your question is _not_ about the practical how-to code this, I simply do not really understand how I can be more specific in my suggestions.

Comment: Well....I just need more examples(websites). And my problems it that I really cant find enough. For example, in expo.getbootstrap.com, there isn't too much in this style.(But itself is one)

Comment: ... but you are not looking for the _function_ but the layout style? So it is not technically the _layout_ as such, as you have decided on the "boxes within columns", so then it is a question of what to put in them? or fonts? or images? Sorry, I seem not to understand the problem :-S

Comment: I think I'd better re-prhase it as 'Where can I find more website with style like medium, getpocket, readwrite, in which the information(stories/posts/links) are presented like a little rectangle'? Pretty much like metro style. It is in contrast to the traditional blog layout (there is no framing of the information)